# update() or repaint() fails to trigger paintEvent()

Tags: qt4, repaint

I have a QScrollArea fathering my awesome scrolling widget. I like to do updates on the contents on various occasions.

For this I did an override of `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)`. Then everytime I want it to be done I call `update()` on the widget.

**Problem:** `paintEvent()` is never called by this!

What I tried in troubleshooting so far:

- Use `repaint()` instead of `update()`. Should call it instantanously. Unfortunately does not.
- Test for `isVisible()` and `updatesEnabled`
- Test wether my override is correct. **Resizing the window calls my function.** Only my manual update(), repaint() calls fail.
- Implement a QTimer to trigger update() or repaint() every 500ms. The trigger gives text output, the function is not called.

Anybody got an idea what to check next? What could make repaint() *not* call paintEvent()?

Comment: Not drawing on the QScrollArea, but instead its assigned QLabel solved the problem for me. I get the update()s for the QLabel.

Comment: could you paste in your header / class definition? Do you have all of your Q_OBJECT macros in there? also give a quick snippet on how you are overriding your paintEvent()...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The solution is to call `this->viewport()->repaint()` or `this->viewport()->update()` from your `QAbstractScrollArea` derived class instead of just `repaint()` or `update()`.

More info is given in [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport):

> `QWidget * QAbstractScrollArea::viewport () const`
>
> Returns the viewport widget.
>   Use the `QScrollArea::widget()` function to retrieve the contents of the viewport widget.

Since the contents that we have in our `QAbstractScrollArea` derived class will be displayed in the viewport widget, makes sense to call viewport widget's update or repaint to draw our data again (have our `paintEvent` called).

Comment: Basically this is the correct answer. My fault was that I created my custom widget from QScrollArea and thought I could do my individual drawing there. Instead, I would have to override the viewport's drawing function, probably not possible.

Comment: It is possible to override viewport's drawing function. Only thing you need to take care of inside viewport's reimplemented paintEvent() is- Instead of passing "this" pointer as one would normally do while creating a QPainter object, pass this->viewport(). QPainter(this->viewport()) instead of QPainter(this). Otherwise "QPainter is not active" error is thrown.

Comment: This applies to any 'fancy' widget that uses a QAbstractScrollArea, like the QTableWidget.  Thanks a ton for pointing this out!

Comment: Spent three hours on this same issue. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I don't know how often I tapped into this trap although I already should know better. It seems that roughly once per year I write a custom widget derived from `QAbstractScrollArea`. This is rare enough to forget about this specific fact so that it hits me again every time. :-( I hope this answer will never age and come to the rescue and as a reminder not to mention that I would appreciate if this would've been fixed in Qt. Or is there a case where `QAbstractScrollArea::update()` would be called intentionally?